# NP and finite automata

Tags: complexity-theory, np

A language $L$ is in NP if and only if there exist polynomial $q$, and a deterministic polynomial Turing machine $M$ such that, for all $x\in L$, there is a string $y$ such that $|y|\leq q(|x|)$ and $M(x,y) = 1$.

My question is is it possible to exchange $M$ for a finite automaton?

Thank you

Comment: Of course, but you won't be defining NP then.

Answer (score 2):

What you have given is a definition. You can define anything you want.  The class of languages defined as

> A language $L$ is in **UC** (user71565's class<sup>1</sup>) if there are a polynomial $q$ and a DFA $A$ such that $x\in L$ if and only if there is some string $y$ with $|y|\leq q(|x|)$ and $A$ accepts $xy$

is a perfectly legitimate class of languages.  For example, it includes all regular langauges (take $y=\varepsilon$ for every $x$).

However, because this is not the same definition as the definition of **NP** that you quoted in your question, you shouldn't expect that **UC$\,=\,$NP**.  In fact, we can quickly see that **UC$\,\neq\,$NP**, using the pumping lemma and a language such as $\{0^n1^n\mid n\geq 0\}$, which is in **NP** but cannot be recognized by any DFA.

Interestingly, though, the following definition *is* equivalent to the normal definition of **NP**:

> A language $L$ is in **NP2** if there are a polynomial $q$ and a deterministic logspace Turing machine $M$ such that $x\in L$ if and only if there is some string $y$ with $|y|\leq q(|x|)$ and $M(x,y)=1$.

That is, we can weaken from a deterministic polynomial-time verifier to a deterministic logspace one, without changing the class of languages defined. This is a consequence of [Fagin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fagin%27s_theorem), which says that the verifier can actually be a formula of first-order logic.  The expressive power of first-order formulas is strictly weaker than deterministic logspace Turing machines.

---

<sup>1</sup> There's something of a tradition of naming language classes in this way. For example, the class **NC** of languages decidable in polylog time with polynomially many processors stands for "Nick's class", after Nick Pippenger.

Comment: Just a note that it isn't clear that the pumping lemma immediately disproves this since we aren't actually testing strings of the form 0^n1^n, we're testing that plus a validator, which could be regular.

Comment: @JeremyWest It is immediately clear. The same proof that $\{0^n1^n\mid n\geq 0\}$ isn't regular tells you that the concatenation of that language with any (not necessarily even regular) language $L$ is also non-regular. Intuitively, an automaton that decided such a concatenation would have to have already decided by the time it had finished reading the prefix, whether or not that prefix was of the form $0^n1^n$.

Comment: Sure, and now it's clear. I just wanted to make sure OP realized that some mention at least of the implication for concatenation was warranted. In other words, to keep straight that there are two languages in play here, and only one is being checked by the verifying machine. FWIW, I had already upvoted your answer when I left my comment :).

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible because finite automata is not equivalent to Turing machine. Turing machine is a powerful model of computation as compared to finite automata. For example

> $$ L= \{0^n1^{2n} \mid n \ge 0\}$$

It is not a regular language but it is verifiable in polynomial time by Turing machine. If you use finite automata as a verifier instead of Turing machine you will be able to verify only regular languages but not all the problems in the complexity class $ \mathsf{\text{}NP}$.

Comment: That's not quite true. Your reasoning for why this is probably false is good. But the claim would be that NP languages can be verified by regular languages, not that they are regular themselves.

Comment: ALL NP Languages can not be verified by DFA (regular language) , see the language given in the answer it is not regular but it is in NP class